# @media queries for mobile - Portrait vs Landscape

Tags: css, media-queries, landscape-portrait

I am using media queries to address mobile screens.

Issue i am facing is with text on the header with **Portrait** vs **Landscape**.
The landscape "**top**" property takes over the portrait one.
Meaning; to position the landscape text properly, on the portrait it gets positioned too high!
Any idea what's the solution to this? How to get portrait and landscape to respect each-other properties and not overtake each-other?

Or how would you approach it?

```
/* Mobile Portrait */
@Media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#one{
position: relative;
top: 310px;
}
 }

/* Mobile Landscape */
@Media only screen and (max-width: 734px) {
#one{
position: relative;
top: 230px;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reverse the order since <480 is also <784 it is following the rule that is last in the order.
Try using this, I usually put the media queries in order of largest to smallest.

```
/* Mobile Landscape */
@Media only screen and (max-width: 734px) {
    #one{
        position: relative;
        top: 230px;
    }
 }
/* Mobile Portrait */
@Media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #one{
        position: relative;
        top: 310px;
     }
}
```

Comment: That worked thank you!

I am now dealing with different sizes in landscape mode; and it's tricky.
For instance Nokia Lumia 920 in Landscape mode doesn't even display the header text like most other mobile phones do.
If you have something you can chime in that will make the process easier let me know.

I am looking to address most screen sizes, but it's something i didn't yet understood well since i am new to media queries.

Otherwise the process might be just the way it is. A bit tedious :)

Comment: Maybe try changing the max-width to 992? for the first query. Don't forget to upvote if my answer worked!

Comment: I upvoted you!
Changing the max-width to 992 did not work, but i will continue trying stuff out as i am new to media queries so i still have a lot to learn.